# jquery $.each nested in another $each. getting data from a JSON

Tags: jquery, html, json, nested, each

I want to get all the values from a **JSON** like this:

> ```
> {
>   "id" : "1",
>   "latitude" : "-3.7462186",
>   "longitude" : "-38.5394332",
>   "array":["9","2","3"]
> }
> {
>   "id" : "2",
>   "latitude" : "-3.9082186",
>   "longitude" : "-3.5394332",
>   "array":["1","1","1"]
> }
> {
>   "id" : "3",
>   "latitude" : "-4.7462186",
>   "longitude" : "-35.5394332",
>   "array":["2","2","3"]
>  }
> ```

And put them in a HTML Table.
I tried to do that using the **$.getJSON method with two nested $.each** (jQuery) to try to get all the values (including the arrays values) for each of these objects and put them in a table in the same order:

> ```
> $.getJSON(URL, function (value) {
>     $.each(value, function(i,e) {
>         $('#table').append('<tr> <td>'+ e.id+'</td> <td>'+ e.latitude +'</td> <td> '+e.longitude+'</td> ');
>            $.each(e.array,function(i)
>             {
>                $('#table').append('<td>'+e.array[i]+'</td>');
>             });
>         });
>       $('#table').append('</tr>');
>     }
>  });
> ```

But the problem is that the 'id','latitude' and 'longitude' from each object is put in the correct row and **all the array values' are put in the last row**.

Like this:

> ```
> id     |   latitude   |   longitude   |   array1  |  array2  |  array3  |
>   1    |  -3.7462186  |  -38.5394332  |
>   2    |  -3.9082186  |  -3.5394332   |
>   3    |  -4.7462186  |  -35.5394332  |
>   9    |      2       |      3        |     1     |    1     |   1     |   2    |    2   |   3
> ```

Which is the **correct nested structure** that I have to follow to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to debug using console.log()? If not, could you please do that and find out what the values are within every `$.each`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `.append()` when used with strings must have the whole string complete with opening and closing tags. Otherwise it will close all elements that do not have corresponding closing tags. The following approach puts together the full string, `row`, first before passing it to `.append()`.

```
var row = '';
$.each(value, function(i,e) {
    row =  '<tr> <td>'+ e.id+'</td> <td>'+ e.latitude +'</td> <td> '+e.longitude+'</td> ';
    $.each(e.array,function(i)  {
        row += '<td>'+e.array[i]+'</td>';
    });
});
row += '</tr>';
$('#table tbody').append( row );
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the innermost `each` to:

```
        $.each(e.array,function(ind, obj)
        {
           $('#table').append('<td>'+obj+'</td>');
        });
```